# Content-Length Header missing from Nginx-backed Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, http-headers

I've a rails app that serves large static files to registered users. I was able to implement it by following the excellent guide here: [**Protected downloads with nginx, Rails 3.0, and #send_file**](http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/637725747/nginx-rails-send-file). The downloads and everything else is working great, but there is just this problem - The `Content-Length` header isn't being sent.

[image: No Content Length Header]

It's okay for small files, but it gets really frustrating when large files are downloaded, since download managers and browsers don't show any progress. How can I fix this? Do I have to add something to my `nginx` configuration or do I have to pass along some other option to the `send_file` method in my rails controller? I have been searching online for quite some time but have been unsuccessful. Please Help! Thanks!

Here's my `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.awesomeapp.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/deploy/apps/awesomeapp/current/public;

  location ~ /downloads/(.*) {
    internal;
    alias /home/deploy/uploads/$1;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header X-Sendfile-Type X-Accel-Redirect;
    proxy_set_header X-Accel-Mapping /downloads/=/home/deploy/uploads/;

    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, here's something. I don't know if it's the right way or not but I was able to fix the issue by manually sending the `Content-Length` Header from my Rails `Controller`. Here's what I'm doing:

```
def download
    @file = Attachment.find(params[:id])

    response.headers['Content-Length'] = @file.size.to_s
    send_file(@file.path, x_sendfile: true)
end
```

`nginx` should be automatically able to set the header. There must be something that I'm missing; but until I find a 'proper' solution, I guess this will have to do.

P.S: The Header needs to be a string to work properly with some webservers, hence the `.to_s`