# How to set content length by send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendfile

I don't know how to set content-length by `send_file`.

I checked the api, there's no content-length param.

Answer (score 15):

You can set headers for response like:

```
def download
  @file = Attachment.find params[:id]

  response.headers['Content-Length'] = @file.size.to_s
  send_file @file.path, :x_sendfile => true
end
```

More info about response object you can find on [official docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-response-object).

P.S: The Header needs to be a string to work properly with some webservers.

Comment: thank man!  but I got a error 502: Bad Gateway / nginx/1.4.1 , 
I can't upload image now , sorry

Comment: Are you uploading or downloading image from your application?

Comment: downloading generated zip, I'm using nginx, is it a rails or nginx config error ?

Comment: You can check your application log, but i think 502 is come from nginx. Also check for nginx's `error.log` and `access.log` for more info.

Comment: Looks like a copy/paste of this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726345/content-length-header-missing-from-nginx-backed-rails-app

Comment: This doesn't work in Rails 3+ as it sends a chunked stream.